# Multiples POST calls in pipe not being executed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am new to angular and really do know what the issue is but I have a method with a pipe like this, so far just one config is needed and this work ok

```
.pipe(
     .
     .
    //addConfigToUser is a POST call
    flatMap(() => this.service.addConfigToUser(config))
     .
     .
)
```

But now I need to modify the method in order to execute the same post request for each entry in the config, but for some reasons that is not the case

```
.pipe(
    .
    .
    flatMap(() => configElemnt.map(
      //addConfigToUser is a POST call
      config => this.service.addConfigToUser(configElemnt)
    .
    .
    ))
```

A workaround would be accessing to the index and in that way the job is done, like this:

```
pipe(
    .
    .
    //addConfigToUser is a POST call
    flatMap(() => this.service.addConfigToUser(config[0])),
    flatMap(() => this.service.addConfigToUser(config[1]))
    .
    .
)
```

Is not throwing any error, but neither do the POST request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `forkJoin` for this:

```js
.pipe(
  flatMap(
    () => forkJoin(
      ...configElemnt.map(cfg => this.service.addConfigToUser(cfg))
    )
  ),
)
```

Notice that `forkJoin` will emit an array of resulted values if all the provided observables **emit at least once** and **complete**.